# How to Produce a Round 's' When the 's' is Immediately Followed by a 't' Using the pgothfamily Font

Tags: fonts, symbols, luatex, german, pgothic

Consider the code which I compile with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgothic,yfonts}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\noindent pgothic font:
\vspace*{10pt}

\textbf{\pgothfamily{Kleins}}
\vskip 5pt
\textbf{\pgothfamily{Kleinstadt}}

\vskip 25pt

\noindent schwabacher font with long-s correction:
\vspace*{10pt}

\textbf{\textswab{Kleins:}}
\vskip 5pt
\textbf{\textswab{Kleins:tadt}}

\vskip 25pt

\noindent pgothic font with same long-s correction:
\vspace*{10pt}

\textbf{\pgothfamily{Kleins:tadt}}
\end{document}
```

and which produces the output

[image]

Notice from the first part of the output that `\pgothfamily` seems to naturally display a round s; except, that is, when a 't' immediately follows the 's' in the word---in this case, "kleinstadt".

However, when using the `schwabacher` font, as in the second part of the output, the correction of replacing the 's' by 's:' works fine in both instances, which otherwise in both cases would have produced an old-style German long-s.

But, applying the same fix to "kleinstadt" using the `\pgothfamily` font merely replaces the 's' by 's:' yielding "kleins:tadt" (with the round s, however).

QUESTION: When using the `pgothfamily` font, how may I produce a round 's' when a 't' immediately follows the letter 's' in the word? I compile the MWE with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `Klein{}stadt` or `Klein\/stadt`? (Can't test now.)

Comment: @Mico German is not my native language. "Klein" made me think of Felix Klein. I hope I didn't commit too great of a faux pas.

Comment: @Mico Perhaps "kleinst" would have been a better choice.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the scolding. I shall try to be more careful about my choice of wording in the future.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your comment. I've got one coming with "breakfast".

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure what you mean? In my comment, I meant that I was already in the process of putting together a related question in which I use the word "breakfast".  just posted it. I certainly meant no offence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break the ligature. There is no built-in method, as far as I can see.

The simplest method is to use `s\/t`.

The difference is that the `yfonts` *do* define a ligature `s:` to produce the “round s”, whereas `pgoth10` doesn't.

Note that `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is not really recommended with LuaLaTeX and you'll get the same font anyway.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgothic}

\begin{document}

{\pgothfamily{Kleins\/tadt}}

{\pgothfamily{Kleins:tadt}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again @egreg.